# How to mask the last 8 digits of an ip

Tags: php

I am working on poll system. I want to restrict the user to vote only once according to their ip address, but to keep the user ip private I need to hide the last 8 digits of the ip address. An example of what I want to achieve is to change this `150.62.48.220` to `15x.xx.xx.xxx`. I hope that someone knows an answer to hiding the last 8 digits of an ip address.

Comment: What have you tried **yourself**?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the last 8 bits, not 8 digits.

Comment: @tereško I have tried what I posted above, but that only takes care of the last and manualy changing where I want the 'x' to be isn't the best way of hiding it.

Comment: No, you copied the code above somewhere on the internet. It did not work. So instead of **trying something yourself**, you decided to outsource the thinking.

Comment: @NigelRen I realy mean the last 8 digits, because the ip address goes into the database(in the form of digits with '.' between the digits). These ip addresses are also displayed in the poll logs(only visible inside of the admin area)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways I would do it, one which only works for IPV4 addresses, the other for IPV4 and IPV6.

```
$ip = "128.123.1.2";

echo rtrim(long2ip(ip2long($ip) & (~255)),"0")."x".PHP_EOL; // 128.123.1.x
```

This is the shortest version, just works for IPV4 and works by converting the IP address to a long (`ip2long()`), masks off the bottom 8 bits(`& (~255)`), converts this back to an IP string, which will always end in `0`.  So remove that and replace it with a `x`.

```
echo maskLastSegment("128.123.1.1").PHP_EOL; // 128.123.1.x
echo maskLastSegment("2001:0db8:85a3:0000:0000:8a2e:0370:7334").PHP_EOL; // 2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:x

function maskLastSegment ( $ip )    {
    $ipaddr =  inet_pton($ip);
    if ( strlen($ipaddr) == 4 ) {
        $ipaddr[3] = chr(0);
    }
    else    {
        $ipaddr[14] = chr(0);
        $ipaddr[15] = chr(0);
    }

    return rtrim(inet_ntop($ipaddr),"0")."x";
}
```

This version works for both types of IP address, using `inet_pton()` to convert the address to a packed number, then according to the type of address, replaces the last digit with 0 (for IPV6, this is actually two bytes).  Then it does the same as the first option, convert it back to a string and remove the last `0` and add an `x`.

(extra one) Just treat an IPV4 address as a string, explode it by '.' and rebuild it all but the last one...

```
$ip = "128.123.1.2";
list($s1,$s2,$s3,$s4) = explode(".", $ip);
echo $s1.".".$s2.".".$s3.".x"; // 128.123.1.x
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am going to give this a shot and let you know the result.

Comment: It is not a good idea to replace 0 with `x`. An ip address can have zeros and we don't want to replace that with `x`.

Comment: @KuldeepSaxena, the question is about replacing trailing bits with x, so not sure why you say *An ip address can have zeros and we don't want to replace that with x*

Comment: @NigelRen What about `2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:7334`?
Would your code return `2001:db8:85a3::8a2e:370:x`?

Comment: @KuldeepSaxena, have you tried it, the code is in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you what to convert and array `a.b.c.d` to `a.b.c.x`

You can convert to array, splice it and then implode it.

i.e.

```
$new_ip = implode('.', array_slice(explode('.', $ip), 0, 3)) . '.x';
```